# JOIN by mapping multiple values and conditions in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, join, mapping

Suppose:

tbl_a:

```
id hobby   type
1  fishing man
2  movie   woman
```

tbl_b:

```
id hobby   type
1  game    boy
2  dance   girl
```

I'd like `man=boy, woman=girl` when doing join operation

```
select a.type,a.hobby, b.hobby
from tbl_a a 
join tbl_b b
on a.type=b.type
```

will result

```
type  hobby   hobby
man   fishing game
woman movie   dance
```

Can it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this:

```
SELECT a.type, a.hobby, b.hobby
FROM tbl_a a
JOIN tbl_b b ON (a.type = 'man' AND b.type = 'boy') OR
                (a.type = 'woman' AND b.type = 'girl');
```

The `JOIN` condition is simply a `boolean` expression and you can specify whatever condition you want to join on, including disparate values in both relations ('man', 'boy') and separate additive conditions (by both genders).

Comment: ha. so cute! I know this way, just forgot it. Thank you.